# Aplicación deja de funcionar al crear instalador C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en visual studio, la he terminado y deseo probarla en otros equipos pero al generar el instalador (He utilizado advanced installer y publicarla desde visual studio y en ambas pasa lo mismo) e instalarla no pasa del login, aun cuando compilando en visual studio funciona perfectamente, no me tira ningún error, solo cuando ingreso usuario y contraseña se congela y posteriormente se cierra, hay alguna forma de poder depurar la aplicación en este punto ya que al estar generado el instalador no me muestra ningún msj de error.

Comment: la app se conecta a una base de datos ? si es asi validaste que el connection string este correcto y la pc pueda alcanzar el servidor, la forma de depurar es que pongas codigo de log en un archivo y vayas registrando por donde pasa la ejecucion, bueno en realidad hay una opcion de remote debug, pero no funciona si instalas, deberias poner los .pdb y la app compilada en debug para poder adjuntarte al proceso, por eso es as facil poner codigo de log que registre

Comment: La BD es un fichero local de sqlite que se encuentra en mis documentos, pero si no la encontrará no tiraría una execpion? Simplemente se congela.

Comment: si pero puede que justamente el exception sea el que cierra la aplicacion, cuando accedes a la db recuerda defir el try..catch para controlarlo y es alli donde puede mostrar o loguear el problema

Comment: A qué se podría deberse que funcione bien al compilar y luego con el instalador no? No entiendo que funcione en un escenario si y en el otro no.

Comment: pueden ser miles de cosas, desde temas de permisos de acceso a simplemente no controlar los tipos de datos, valores nulos, etc, a veces no es un problema en el codigo sino en la falta de alguna validacion vinculada a los datos, por eso decia que lo mejor es generar log para entender que puede estar pasando

Comment: crea un log en la aplicacion, pon try catch en donde puedas, y cada vez que entre por el catch pon una linea en el log con lo que el ex.message y tambien añade en que funcion/procedure ha fallado y que valores de entrada le han llegado. Con eso te sera mas facil reproducir el error en debug

Comment: posiblemente la base de datos quede bloqueada por algun otro proceso, entonces al tratar de conectarse se queda esperando (se congela), hay un timeout por que el archivo nunca respondio, ahi es donde se cierra tu apliacion